# Why does my single-thread python program use 3000% cpu power?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, cpu-usage

My python 2.7 program with 'tensorflow-gpu' and 'numpy' run on a 32 cores CPU and 4 Nvidia Tesla K80 GPUs Server on ubuntu. When i use 'top', i find it use over 3000% cpu power. Why does this happen? It is only a single-threaded program.

Comment: It is not, `tensorflow` is smart enough to use as much resource as possible.

Comment: I recall some nvidia software versions do the same with windows taskmanager. I had to reset a value in the regedit to correct it. Start looking in such corner for the issue. But 32cpu core is 4x8 I'd say... Driver cpu/mobo issue may also a shady corner to look at.

Comment: @Sraw I also wrote a 'tensorflow' program a few days ago, but it only use one core. I really can't find the difference between the way i use 'tensorflow'. It is amazing

Comment: You will want to look at your [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)-setup. If build with support for OpenMP, it will automatically parallelize matrix and vector operations. (same for numpy, scipy, sklearn ...). (of course different NN architectures and batch-sizes limit the amount of parallelization which is possible)